# how to target ul li input checkbox items in javascript using .siblings()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have the following javascript code that works perfectly for most checkboxes, where the script determines if more than 1 checkbox is selected and if so it hides the rest of the checkboxes:

```
var limit = 1;

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(evt) {
    console.log('checkboxSelectedLimit: detects checkbox');
    if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
        this.checked = false;
        console.log('too many checkboxes selected');
    }
});
```

using the following html structure:

```
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
```

yet when I move my checkboxes into an ordered list like below:

```
<ul>
    <li><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2</li>
    <li><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3</li>
    <li><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4</li>
    <li><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5</li>
    <li><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1</li>
</ul>
```

my javascript does fire that it is checked, but th `.siblings()` doesn't seem to be firing as it does not work. i assume i am needing to update this script to target items in an `ul li`, yet when i change:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(evt)
```

to

```
$('ul li input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(evt)
```

it does not work.

any help would be greatly appreciated by someone smarter than myself.

Comment: It's not your event handler that needs to be changed. Your issue is that your inputs are no longer siblings of one another when they're in a list. On a separate note, if you're only allowing one checkbox to be checked at a time, why aren't you using radio buttons instead?

Comment: good point. i've changed the code to use radio buttons elsewhere; and using this script for checkboxes in another part of the application thanks for bringing that up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is li > input, so you need to find li objects instead.

```js
var limit = 1;

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(evt) {
        console.log('checkboxSelectedLimit: detects checkbox');
        if($(this).parent().siblings().find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length >= limit) {
            this.checked = false;
            console.log('too many checkboxes selected');
        }
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2</li>
<li><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3</li>
<li><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4</li>
<li><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5</li>
<li><input class="single-checkbox"type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather then tying your selector to the dom structure which you may want to change again in the future and then break this all over again, I would recommend targeting the checkboxes by name.

So instead of this line:

```
if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
```

Try something like this:

```
if($('input[name=vehicle]:checked').length >= limit) {
```

Or even better, grab the input name dynamically using the name already in **$(this)**:

```
if($('input[name=' + $(this).attr('name') + ']:checked').length >= limit) {
```